# Eigenspace calculation?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Based on $\lambda$ of 4 I got the below matrix in reduced row echelon form

$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & \frac{1}{3} & -\frac{1}{3} \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right)$$

Based on this if I take $$x+1/3y-1/3z=0$$ if I set y=s and z=t then I get eigen vectors

First case s=1 and t=0   $$\left(\begin{array}{aaa}
-1/3\\
1\\
0
\end{array}\right)$$ Second case s=0 and t=1

$$\left(\begin{array}{aaa}
1/3\\
0\\
1
\end{array}\right)$$

My questions are:

Q1) Based some model answers $$[ (1,0,3);(-1,3,0);(1,-1,1) ]$$ are my results equivalent and if they are how would I have gotten to the same result?

Q2) How would I get the third vector which is missing from my calculations? $$i.e. (1,-1,1)$$